# Multiple bar chat with Flot with x-axis string

Tags: flot

i am using `float` charts. i faced a problem with `multiplebar` chart. when i am trying to get x-axis as "`string`" it shows only single bar. i need to show x-axis ticks  in form for sting like city names.HOW CAN I GET MULTIPLE BARS WITH X-AXIS as string?

```
my code:
$(function () {
var previousPoint;


 var d1 = [ ["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9] ];
 var d2 = [ ["January", 5], ["February", 2], ["March", 11], ["April", 2], ["May", 5], ["June", 12] ];
 var d3 = [ ["January", 11], ["February", 12], ["March", 6], ["April",8], ["May", 11], ["June",16] ];
 var ds = new Array();

ds.push({
    data:d1,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        barWidth: 0.2, 
        order: 1,
        lineWidth : 2
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:d2,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        barWidth: 0.2, 
        order: 2
    }
});
ds.push({
    data:d3,
    bars: {
        show: true, 
        barWidth: 0.2, 
        order: 3
    }
});

//tooltip function
function showTooltip(x, y, contents, areAbsoluteXY) {
    var rootElt = 'body';

    $('<div id="tooltip" class="tooltip-with-bg">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        'z-index':'1010',
        top: y,
        left: x
    }).prependTo(rootElt).show();
}


//Display graph
$.plot($("#placeholder"), ds, {
xaxis: { mode: "categories",
      tickLength: 0


} ,
    grid:{
        hoverable:true
    },

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass strings in as month data. If you want to use months have a look at the flot api - https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md

This fiddle might help you as well - http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ2Y/3/

```
var m1 = {
data : [[1356998400000,14.72]],    
bars: { barWidth: 60*60*24*31*1000 }
};

var m2 = {
data : [[1359676800000,30.74]],
bars: { barWidth: 60*60*24*1000 *28 }
};

var m3 = {
data : [[1362096000000,18.57]],
bars: { barWidth: 60*60*24*31*1000 }
};
```

Comment: it was suitable for time based values.but i need to show custom string as x-axis like city names.And i need to show multiple bars for a single city.

Comment: this code is fine:

var d1 = [ [1, 10], [2, 8], [3, 4], [4, 13], [5, 17], [6, 9] ];
var d2 = [ [1, 5], [2, 2], [3, 11], [4, 2],[6, 12] ];
var d3 = [ [1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 6], [4,8], [5, 11], [6,16] ];
var d4 = [ [1, 2], [2, 8], [3,11], [4,15], [5, 7], [6,10] ];

and
    xaxis : {
       ticks: [[1, "hyd"], [2, "vsp"], [3, "newyork"],[4,"london"],[5,"tokyo"],[6,"mumbai"]],
     
    } ,